# I'm creating a spin wheel, and I want to submit the answer, which comes after spinning to my email by clicking the button appears after the spin

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a spin wheel for my friend at her birthday, and I want to submit the p.innerHTML, where p is the prize won after spinning to my email by clicking the button which appears after the spin is completed.

Error  : game.js:118 Uncaught TypeError: ans.innerHTML.submit is not a function.

Here is my js code :

```
// the game itself
var game;
// the spinning wheel
var wheel;
// can the wheel spin?
var canSpin;
// slices (prizes) placed in the wheel
var slices = 8;
// prize names, starting from 12 o'clock going clockwise
var slicePrizes = [
  "set of Earrings,a perfect match for your fashion.",
  "teddy, your new bedtime friend.",
  "Personal Diary, to save your beautiful memories.",
  "choice, you can choose your own gift !",
  "chocolates, as sweet as you.",
  "cup, your new tea-time partner.",
  "ring, shiny like you.",
  "pendant, so you will never get out of fashion.",
];
// the prize you are about to win
var prize;
// text field where to show the prize
var p;
// submit button
var btn;

window.onload = function () {
  // creation of a 458x488 game
  game = new Phaser.Game(458, 488, Phaser.AUTO, "");
  // adding "PlayGame" state
  game.state.add("PlayGame", playGame);
  // launching "PlayGame" state
  game.state.start("PlayGame");
};

// PLAYGAME STATE

var playGame = function (game) {};

playGame.prototype = {
  // function to be executed once the state preloads
  preload: function () {
    // preloading graphic assets
    game.load.image("wheel", "wheel.png");
    game.load.image("pin", "pin.png");
  },
  // funtion to be executed when the state is created
  create: function () {
    // giving some color to background
    game.stage.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    // adding the wheel in the middle of the canvas
    wheel = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "wheel");
    // setting wheel registration point in its center
    wheel.anchor.set(0.5);
    // adding the pin in the middle of the canvas
    var pin = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "pin");
    // setting pin registration point in its center
    pin.anchor.set(0.5);
    // creating Prize element
    p = document.createElement("div");
    p.style.position = "absolute";
    p.style.top = "70%";
    p.style.left = "50%";
    p.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
    p.style.fontSize = "2.5em";
    p.style.color = "Red";
    p.style.fontWeight = "700";
    p.style.padding = "3%";
    p.style.width = "80%";
    // creating submit button
    btn = document.createElement("Button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Submit Your Gift";
    btn.style.position = "absolute";
    btn.style.top = "90%";
    btn.style.left = "50%";
    btn.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
    btn.style.fontSize = "1.5em";
    btn.style.padding = "2%";
    btn.style.width = "60%";
    btn.style.borderRadius = "20px";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "lightpink";
    // the game has just started = we can spin the wheel
    canSpin = true;
    // waiting for your input, then calling "spin" function
    game.input.onDown.add(this.spin, this);
  },
  // function to spin the wheel
  spin() {
    // can we spin the wheel?
    if (canSpin) {
      // resetting text field
      p.innerHTML = "";
      //resetting button
      btn.style.display = "none";
      // the wheel will spin round from 2 to 4 times. This is just coreography
      var rounds = game.rnd.between(2, 4);
      // then will rotate by a random number from 0 to 360 degrees. This is the actual spin
      var degrees = game.rnd.between(0, 360);
      // before the wheel ends spinning, we already know the prize according to "degrees" rotation and the number of slices
      prize = slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / slices));
      // now the wheel cannot spin because it's already spinning
      canSpin = false;
      // animation tweeen for the spin: duration 3s, will rotate by (360 * rounds + degrees) degrees
      // the quadratic easing will simulate friction
      var spinTween = game.add.tween(wheel).to(
        {
          angle: 360 * rounds + degrees,
        },
        3000,
        Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.Out,
        true,
      );
      // once the tween is completed, call winPrize function
      spinTween.onComplete.add(this.winPrize, this);
    }
  },
  // function to assign the prize
  winPrize() {
    // now we can spin the wheel again
    canSpin = false;
    // writing the prize you just won
    p.innerHTML = "Yippe, you won a " + slicePrizes[prize];
    btn.style.display = "block";
    document.body.appendChild(p);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.onclick = function () {
      btn.type = "submit";
      btn.formAction = "mailto:techboy730@gmail.com";
      var ans = document.createElement("p");
      ans.id = "a";
      ans.innerHTML = p.innerHTML;
      ans.innerHTML.submit();
    };
  },
};
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
   <script src = "game.js"></script>
  <title>Ayusha Birthday</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="sec-t">
    <h1 class="top-h">
      Birthday Wheel</h1>
    <p class="top-p">
      let's your luck decide your gift;
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="confettis">
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
  <div class="confetti"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my output after spin :

[image: Here is how my output looks, after spinning :]

Comment: The `.submit()` function is used on forms to submit them, `innerHTML` returns a `DOMString`, so that function won't work. It would be nice to see your HTML code. See  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you please help me to reach the result, because I'm trying this since last night and didn't reach anywhere, and my friend's birthday is tomorrow, and I want to surprise her at midnight.

Comment: Well thanks I got the hint, from you comments, thanks so much, and If I get the results, I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by the hint provided by bluevultutre in the comments section. I created a form, then converted my btn to type submit and created a hidden element to store the prize won.

This is the answer to the above question :

Here is my js :

```
// the game itself
var game;
// the spinning wheel
var wheel; 
// can the wheel spin?
var canSpin;
// slices (prizes) placed in the wheel
var slices = 8;
// prize names, starting from 12 o'clock going clockwise
var slicePrizes = ["set of Earrings,a perfect match for your fashion.", "teddy, your new bedtime friend.", "Personal Diary, to save your beautiful memories.", "choice, you can choose your own gift !", "chocolates, as sweet as you.", "cup, your new tea-time partner.", "ring, shiny like you.", "pendant, so you will never get out of fashion."];
// the prize you are about to win
var prize;
// text field where to show the prize
var p;
// submit button
var btn;

window.onload = function() {    
     // creation of a 458x488 game
    game = new Phaser.Game(458, 488, Phaser.AUTO, "");
     // adding "PlayGame" state
     game.state.add("PlayGame",playGame);
     // launching "PlayGame" state
     game.state.start("PlayGame");
}

// PLAYGAME STATE
    
var playGame = function(game){};

playGame.prototype = {
     // function to be executed once the state preloads
     preload: function(){
          // preloading graphic assets
          game.load.image("wheel", "wheel.png");
        game.load.image("pin", "pin.png");     
     },
     // funtion to be executed when the state is created
    create: function(){
          // giving some color to background
        game.stage.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
          // adding the wheel in the middle of the canvas
        wheel = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "wheel");
          // setting wheel registration point in its center
          wheel.anchor.set(0.5);
          // adding the pin in the middle of the canvas
          var pin = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "pin");
          // setting pin registration point in its center
          pin.anchor.set(0.5);
          // creating Prize element
          p = document.createElement("div");
      p.style.position = "absolute";
      p.style.top = "70%";
      p.style.left = "50%";
      p.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
      p.style.fontSize = "2.5em";
      p.style.color = "Red";
      p.style.fontWeight = "700";
      p.style.padding = "3%";
      p.style.width = "80%";
      // creating submit button
      btn = document.createElement("input");
      btn.setAttribute("type", "submit");
          btn.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
      btn.innerHTML = "Submit Your Gift";
      btn.style.position = "absolute";
      btn.style.top = "90%";
      btn.style.left = "50%";
      btn.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
      btn.style.fontSize = "1.5em";
      btn.style.padding = "2%";
      btn.style.width = "60%";
      btn.style.borderRadius = "20px";
      btn.style.backgroundColor = "lightpink";
          // the game has just started = we can spin the wheel
          canSpin = true;
          // waiting for your input, then calling "spin" function
          game.input.onDown.add(this.spin, this);       
    },
     // function to spin the wheel
     spin(){
          // can we spin the wheel?
          if(canSpin){  
               // resetting text field
           p.innerHTML = "";
           //resetting button
           btn.style.display ="none";
               // the wheel will spin round from 2 to 4 times. This is just coreography
               var rounds = game.rnd.between(2, 4);
               // then will rotate by a random number from 0 to 360 degrees. This is the actual spin
               var degrees = game.rnd.between(0, 360);
               // before the wheel ends spinning, we already know the prize according to "degrees" rotation and the number of slices
               prize = slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / slices));
               // now the wheel cannot spin because it's already spinning
               canSpin = false;
               // animation tweeen for the spin: duration 3s, will rotate by (360 * rounds + degrees) degrees
               // the quadratic easing will simulate friction
               var spinTween = game.add.tween(wheel).to({
                    angle: 360 * rounds + degrees
               }, 3000, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.Out, true);
               // once the tween is completed, call winPrize function
               spinTween.onComplete.add(this.winPrize, this);
          }
     },
     // function to assign the prize
     winPrize(){
          // now we can spin the wheel again
          canSpin = false;
          // writing the prize you just won
      p.innerHTML = "Yippe, you won a " + slicePrizes[prize];
      btn.style.display = "block";
      document.body.appendChild(p);
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
      btn.onclick = function() {
            // Create a form synamically
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "mailto:techboy730@gmail.com");
    form.setAttribute("id", "form1");
    //append the form to the body, to prevent abotion
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    // Create an Hidden Element
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    hiddenInput.style.display = "none";
    hiddenInput.innerHTML = p.innerHTML;
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    form.appendChild(btn);
    form.submit();
         };
}
}
```